# Reference to generic type 'Set' requires arguments in <...> & Generic Parameter 'element' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, storekit

I was working on In-App Purchases and came across two errors.

The first one is `private let productIdentifiers: Set` It comes up with the error **"Reference to generic type 'Set' requires arguments in <...>"**

The second error in my code is `private var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set()`  It comes up with the error **"Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred"**

Here is most of my code near the two errors:

```
public class IAPHelper : NSObject  {

private let productIdentifiers: Set
private var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set()

private var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
private var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

 static let IAPHelperPurchaseNotification =     "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"

public init(productIds: Set<ProductIdentifier>) {
self.productIdentifiers = productIds


super.init()
 }
}
```

Help would be nice!!

EDIT: I now get the error '>' is not a postfix unary operator when I change the second error to `private var purchasedProductIdentifiers =  Set<ProductIdentifier> = Set()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private let productIdentifiers : Set<ProductIdentifier>
private var purchasedProductIdentifiers : Set<ProductIdentifier> = Set()
```

Comment: Now for the second error (private var purchasedProductIdentifiers : Set<ProductIdentifier> = Set() I get the error '>' is not a postfix unary operator

Comment: Please look more carefully at the line in your edit.  Does it match mine?